# Selenium. Как получить текущий html после метода click()?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

После нажатия кнопки на сайте вылезает окно для авторизации (в частности, там находятся поля для логина и пароля). Однако дальше, при поиске этих полей по id, выскакивает NoSuchElementException. Как исправить проблему?

Мой код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
#подключаем драйвер
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\scraper\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
#загружаем сайт и заходим в учетную запись
browser.get('http://www.some_url.ru/')
login = 'login'
password = 'password'
enter = browser.find_element_by_class_name('bfMvh')
enter.click()
browser.find_element_by_id('login').send_keys(login)
browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 4):

Если вам нужно после `click()` дождаться загрузки / подгрузки каких-то данных, нужно сделать ожидание.

У Selenium есть два вида ожиданий: [implicit](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/selenium__examples/about_wait/implicit_waits.py) (не явное) и [explicit](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/selenium__examples/about_wait/explicit_waits.py) (явное).

Об этом можно прочитать в документации: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

---

## Implicit

Достаточно в браузере указать значение `implicitly_wait`.

Например:

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # seconds
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
print('Title: "{}"'.format(driver.title))

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#search').send_keys('Funny cats' + Keys.RETURN)

result_count = driver.find_element_by_id('result-count')
print(result_count.text)
```

Тогда Selenium будет делать поиск элементов в течении указанного времени.

---

## Explicit

Тут уже нужно будет явно вызывать ожидание и условие выхода из ожидания, условия могут быть разные, например: видимость указанного элемента, что он появился в DOM HTML, и т.п.

Пример:

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
print('Title: "{}"'.format(driver.title))

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#search').send_keys('Funny cats' + Keys.RETURN)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)

result_count = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'result-count'))
)
print(result_count.text)
```