# Переход к основной странице после авторизации

Tags: python, selenium

Пишу тесты на Selenium + Python.
Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой:
Есть сайт, у которого при авторизации выходит дополнительное окно.
Но после того, как пройдет авторизацию, не возвращается к основному окну сайта.
Что сделать, чтобы тест проходил после авторизации?

```
pwd = "логин:пароль"
url = 'http://' + pwd + 'всплывающее окно авторизации'
wd: WebDriver = WebDriver()
response = wd.get(url)
wd.get("http://ссылка")# эту ссылку добавила позже, и по ней перешел на другую страницу 
wd.find_element_by_class_name("jss256").click() # но здесь не находит кнопку
print(response)
```

Comment: Нужно после ввода данных в дополнительном окне перейти в корень сайта (/index)?

Comment: я после авторизации добавила ссылку на другую страницу сайта, она сработала, но далее на кнопку, которую нужно нажать по прохождению теста, не нажимает к сожалению.
Traceback (most recent call last):
.... line 13, in <module>
    wd.find_element_by_class_name("jss256").click()

Comment: С этим вопросом, я не думаю что смогу помочь. Зато вы можете помочь другим участникам. Под вопросом есть кнопка `править`, через нее добавьте ваш код. Кода нет, поэтому можно только угадывать, но после клика используется ли какое-то ожидание элемента для клика? Про ожидания я писал тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445