# Как написать автотест на python для входа через соц.сеть

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Учусь автоматизации Python(v3.7)+Selenium, написал по стандарту древний тест для авторизации

```
def test_authorization_google(app):
  app.open_mobile_page()
  app.login_google(username="name@gmail.com", password="password")
  app.logout()

def login_google(self, username, password):
  wd = self.wd
  # нажимаю на кнопку "авторизацию"
  wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".login").click()
  # появилась страница, в которой я нажимаю на кнопку входа через соц сеть
  wd.find_element_by_css_selector(".google").click()
  # тут открываеться попап окно гугл для ввода логин, я его ввожу
  wd.find_element_by_name("identifier").click()
  wd.find_element_by_name("identifier").clear()
  wd.find_element_by_name("identifier").send_keys(username)
  # нажимаю на кнопку "далее"  
  wd.find_element_by_css_selector("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/content/span").click()
  # открылось окно для ввода пароля, я его ввожу
  wd.find_element_by_name("password").click()
  wd.find_element_by_name("password").clear()
  wd.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)
  # нажимаю на кнопку "далее"
  wd.find_element_by_css_selector("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/content/span").click()
```

Вот у меня при запуске открывается дополнительное окно попап для ввода логина, и все, логин не вводится и через время тест падает, может кто подсказать, как правильно написать тест?

Допустим как при авторизации через гугл почту на сайте https://automated-testing.info
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте что `wd.find_element_by_name("identifier")` что-то находит. Возможно, нужно подождать пока страница прогрузится, вот о ожиданиях элементов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445

Comment: да в том то и дело, что не находит, там открываеться новое попап окно, грубо говоря, одна страница накладывается на другую страницу, а вот как перейти и найти елемент я не знаю(

Comment: новое окно? <iframe> что ли?

Comment: я в описании проблемы добавил картинку

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Тыкаете правой кнопкой на окно с `Войти` и выбираете инспектирование элемента и смотрите что это такое. Я думаю что это `iframe`, тогда понадобится код на примере: `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))`

Comment: Спасибо, сделал через driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) ) и заработало

Comment: Вы молодец, что смогли разобраться :)

Answer (score 1):

Автору помог метод [driver.switch_to.window](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to):

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]))
```