# Пишу парсер на python + selenium. Пытаюсь достучаться до элемента, но никак не получается

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Моя задача состоит в том, что мне нужно собрать текст, конкретно из - родителя `<span></span>` но скорее всего метод, который я использую натыкается на дочерний `<span></span>`, а не на текст.

```
<span class="y2">
   <span class="Zt">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
 "sdul3Ishsp"
</span>
```

Я пытаюсь извлечь элемент таким образом:

```
elem_msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name("y2")
elem_msg = elem_msg.text
print(elem_msg)
```

Пытался также указать `("Zt")` но это и так бессмысленно. Пытался перебрать значения с помощью for и использования `find_elements_by_class_name("y2")` - безрезультатно.

Конкретно html взят из Gmail-почты. Ошибка не появляется, но результат не хочет выводиться в консоль. 
Обращаться по имени в моем коде - недопустимо!

Comment: А спан у вас где? Не в выпадающем списке?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, да, в выпадающем списке. Что можете посоветовать?:)

Comment: Для начала раскрыть список)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, пытался уже. Также пытался прописывать через xpath, даже уже на всякий случай попробовал использовать `find_element_by_link_text` - нет никаких результатов:( Результат я пытаюсь записать в массив(кортеж), но потом пытаюсь вывести- а там пусто. Делал точно такой же другой пример, но с указанием другого класса - там работает

Comment: Так вы сначала нажмите, чтобы этот список появился, а потом уже ищите. И лучше сделать задержку после клика на открытие списка и поиском

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, а как конкретнее реализовать это в коде? Моя задача состоит в том, что мне нужно собрать текст именно с этого тэга, конкретно - родителя <span></span> но скорее всего метод натыкается на дочерний <span></span>, а не на текст

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy, настройте ожидание элемента: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445 (советую неявное задавать), пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/67494137a7ba9c7fcf6e54cc88dcc62e60ab13a7/selenium__examples/about_wait/implicit_waits.py#L24