# Selenium не находит кнопку для прикрепления аттача на яндекс почте

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Изначально XPath, скопированный из браузера корректно находился. Теперь перестал. Пробовал копировать XPath и Selector из браузера, но по ним Selenium больше элемент не видит
`//*[@id="nb-1"]/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/label/input`
Элемент: кнопка для отправки аттачей в Яндекс.Почте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: xPath - это зло

Comment: @tCode, частично с вами согласен, css-селекторы более читаемые. Но тут многое зависит от рук, что пишут. Тот, что в вопросе это наверняка скопированный из инспектора браузера *полный* путь, например как и xpath до вашего ника в комментарии `/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]/div/a`, но его можно описать короче и понятнее: `//ul[@class="comments-list js-comments-list"]/li[1]//a[@class="comment-user"]` тут как и с кодом имея желание можно сделать красиво :)

Comment: @Roman, добавьте ваш код, без него можно только гадать, например на тему: настроены ли у вас задержки при поиске элементов? Сразу после загрузки страницы происходит построение DOM, выполнение скриптов и рендеринг элементов. Поиск нужно после этого выполнять. Посмотрите об этом тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445