# как прокрутить страницу до определенного элемента selenium python 3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Ситуация такая я пробую прокрутить вниз до вот этой кнопки
`<button class="_3dxOPpKVs8 _2Hl0nzGgOH _3KEDnFP0dp _3AGrhxH5DS _2UF39lBLOv yYAF4gRW1m" type="button">Load more </button>`
что бы нажать потом снова прокрутить нажат и так пока не исчезнет кнопка.
Если кто может скажите как прокрутить до этой кнопки, вот все что я пробовал.

```
def lookup(driver, timeout):
driver.get("https://sg.carousell.com/categories/property-102/")
scroll_pause_time = timeout
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
while True:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "yYAF4gRW1m")))
    #button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[text='Load more']")
    #button=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Load more')
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("yYAF4gRW1m")
    #button =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Load more']")
    #driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.DOWN)         
    #driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', button)
    #button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    #but=driver.find_element_by_class_name("yYAF4gRW1m")
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", but)
    try:
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
        but.click()
    except WebDriverException:
        soup=BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        return soup
```

Проблема в том что я не могу найти кнопку что бы прокрутить до него, по скольку изначально селен не видит его.Не судите строго я пока учусь. Спасибо за ответ, если будет )).

Comment: Возможно, элемент еще не отрендерился на странице, посмотрите про задержки в моем ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445

Comment: До этого у меня есть функция которая ждет пока страница загрузится полностью.    
def init_driver():
    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
    return driver

Comment: `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "yYAF4gRW1m")))` у вас этот момент выполняется? Драйвер элемент в течении 10 секунд находит?

Comment: Нет не находит, но я еще и без явного ожидания пробовал никак не находит, находит тогда когда страница прокручена вниз.

Comment: Значит, там динамическая прогрузка и/или динамический рендеринг элементов. Т.е. просто прокрутить не выйдет, нужно программно прокручивать страницу вниз и проверять тот элемент

Comment: Если не трудно покажите пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я адаптировал ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/27760083/5909792 с вашим кодом (и уже при написании ответа заметил, что у вас уже был такой пример, но *закомментированный*), пример:

```
driver.get("https://sg.carousell.com/categories/property-102/")
scroll_pause_time = timeout

while True:
    # Проматываем страницу вниз
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "yYAF4gRW1m")))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)  # Для отладки, после удалить
        continue  # Не нашли элемент, попробуем на следующей итерации

    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

    try:
        time.sleep(scroll_pause_time)
        element.click()
    except WebDriverException:
        soup=BS(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
        return soup
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, все работает ))