# Ошибка NoSuchElementException Unable to locate element при нажатии на кнопку в selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Всем добрый день. Пишу парсер Яндекс.Месенджера. Скрипт, переходя по этой ссылке https://yandex.ru/chat/#/
должен нажать на крестик в всплывающем окне:

крестик имеет класс

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="uik-icon-button uik-icon-button_hoverable">…</div>
```

И затем спарсить названия каналов не переходя по ним.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, какой html вам вернулся вообще. Может подождать надо, а может в зависимости от кук и прочего вам вообще другая страница в скрипте приходит. Кстати, там может сначала на принятие кук надо нажать, а потом уже крестик.

Comment: Нужно добавить ожидание, т.к. делая поиск элемента того может и не быть. Например, добавьте драйверу неявное ожидание: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445

Comment: Если вывести html код страницы, то выведется бред, не код от страницы. В основном сообщении дописал

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут есть несколько проблем.

Загружаемая страница реализована используя javascript и основное содержимое загружается уже javascript-ом. Это объясняет то, что в html коде после загрузки не видно содержимого. Содержимое добавляется динамически.

Это приводит к целой серии проблем связанных с тем, что после почти каждого шага программы (например `driver.get('https://yandex.ru/chat/#/')`) в браузере запускается javascript реакция на этот шаг и эта реакция работает асинхронно c вашей программой. Это значит, что ваша программа после каждого шага должна синхронизироваться с тем, что происходит в браузере.

Обычно, это означает ждать, пока не закончится асинхронная операция. Так непосредственно после загрузки, т.е. после выполнения `driver.get('https://yandex.ru/chat/#/')` элемент, который программа пробует найти, еще не добавлен на страницу и программа должна подождать пока это случится, перед тем как она сможет на элемент, например, нажать.

Ожидание можно реализовать несколькими способами (см. например тут https://habr.com/ru/post/273089/).

Например, можно воспользоваться неявным ожиданием:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # все операции будут ждать до 10 секунд
driver.get('https://yandex.ru/chat/#/')
```

Вторая проблема - всплывающее окно о файлах куки. Оно закрывает доступ к кнопке, и пока его не закрыть, кнопку нельзя нажимать (ни вручную ни из селениум).

Делается это приблизительно так:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
btn = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
      (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.lg-cc__button')
    )
) 
btn.click()
```

Обратите внимание, здесь так же приходится ждать пока само окно не станет видимым, потому что окно с куки тоже загружается асинхронно.

Дальше, нужно чтобы программа дождалась, чтобы всплывающее окно о файлах куки полностью закрылось и не мешало нажать на кнопку. Закрытие окна тоже происходит асинхронно.

Я думаю принцип понятен - после каждого шага нужно ждать пока действие в браузере завершится.

Какое конкретно условие нужно ждать - зависит от страницы. Иногда, просто появление элемента в дереве DOM. Иногда, что он появился и видим. Иногда элемент бывает видим - но перекрыт другим полупрозрачным (как в случае с окном о файлах куки) и нужно дождаться когда станет доступен для нажатия.

Ну и еще одна более мелкая проблема - это неправильное использование функции `find_element_by_css_selector`. Она принимает один аргумент имя класса, передавать несколько имен через пробел - нельзя. Замените на `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.uik-icon-button.uik-icon-button_hoverable')`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Подскажите, что такое EC.visibility_of_element_located? EC это вообще от чего и для чего?

Comment: В тексте есть ссылка на объяснение как ждать, какие функции использовать и т.д. https://habr.com/ru/post/273089/. Там все это есть.

Comment: Подскажите с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135262/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python