# Как парсить с помощью selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Всем добрый день. С помощью **selenium** хочу вывести html код этой страницы: https://yandex.ru/chat/#/

Но выводится вообще не код от страницы.
Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://yandex.ru/chat/#/")
    main_page = driver.page_source
    print(main_page)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вот его вывод:

```
<html lang="ru" class="browser windows theme_light"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,shrink-to-fit=no"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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.....**P.S. ТАКИХ 100К ИЕРОГЛИФОВ ЕЩЕ**HbOQSgGJON9169bjYiZ8P1YDGdivbic3cVgOIx8reZQ65c4W6vhUi4H2rlfP3ExYN1Iw0sgPYuLEoBiQZWjQv5Rfz8OBxsfJBxAuV7HjW</iframe></body></html>
```

Подскажите, как раздобыть html код страницы: https://yandex.ru/chat/#/

Может это из-за всплывающихся окон?

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы добавить задержку до `driver.page_source`?

Comment: А что она даст?

Comment: Загружаемая страница реализована используя javascript и основное содержимое загружается уже javascript-ом. Это объясняет то, что в html коде после загрузки не видно содержимого. Содержимое добавляется динамически.

Comment: Понял, а на сколько добавить задержку? 10 секунд?

Comment: Смотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83 там подробнее