# Как нажать на кнопку и спарсить html код на Python?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть парсер на Python, который открывает эту страницу  https://yandex.ru/chat/#/

закрывает всплывающие окна и парсит html код страницы. Но он не работает, возникает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/project/parse_youtube.py", line 27, in <module>


Подскажите, как её исправить?
```

Comment: Когда программа ожидает `.lg-cc__button`, он есть на странице?

Comment: Есть, это селектор от первой кнопки, про куки. Она всплывает со второй кнопкой. Но после первого запуска скрипта уже не выскакивает

Comment: Я не понял, когда случается ошибка описанная в вопросе, то кнопка показывается на экране или нет?

Comment: Первая кнопка не появляется (которая с куки). Появляется вторая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как кнопка с куки появляется не всегда, то программа должна это учитывать. Тут есть одна тонкость, что нельзя просто проверить в начале, есть ли кнопка в окне с куки, т.к. ее может еще не быть, а потом она появится.

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. ждать кнопку в окне с куки, если по таймауту не дождались, считать, что окно куки при этом запуске не появилось и его закрывать не нужно и продолжать дальше.
2. сначала пробовать нажать на кнопку закрытия. Если по таймауту не получилось, проверить есть ли окно куки и закрыть если есть.
3. сделать цикл, который будет работать максимум 10 секунд, и в цикле проверять сразу два условия и действовать в зависимости от того, какое выполняется:

   - кнопка закрытия диалога доступна для нажатия (можно просто пробовать нажимать и если удается - выходить из цикла, а если нет, то игнорировать исключение и проверять второе условие)
   - отображается окно куки (если отображается - закрывать)