# Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

Как отловить элемент на странице с помощью selenium, элемент появляется не сразу, а после выполнения нескольких действий на сайте (без смены страницы/адреса сайта), через консоль браузера не опознается (в консоли ничего не появляется когда вылезает нужный элемент, мб я и неправ).
Конкретно: сайт instagram, элемент который нужно распознать оповещает о том что действие заблокировано (действие подписка, вылезает после достижения лимита подписок).

Comment: Этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s/1135231#1135231) на подобный вопрос может быть полезен

Comment: о, кто то бота для инсты пишет :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать в таком виде:

```
wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ваш селектор на ожидаемый объект'))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так, у меня была похожая ситуация, решил ее при помощи такого метода, при условии если вы знаете By.XPATH.

```
 
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException

def checkFormCall():
    try:
        elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="popup-window-content-im-phone-call-view"]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/span')
        elem.click()
        logger.info('Форма вызова была закрыта')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        logger.info('Форма вызова на странице не найдена')
        return False
```