# Парсер не собирает все данные с страницы из-за AJAX Python

Tags: python, парсер

Я создал парсер который собирает названия продуктов со страницы магазина "ВкусВилл", однако он собирает только 18 названий из-за AJAX. Я попробовал использовать Selenium для погрузки всей страницы, но к сожалению это не помогло.

Код парсера:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'Path to driver')

r = requests.get('https://vkusvill.ru/goods/molochnye_produkty_yaytso/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")

element = soup.find_all('a', class_='ProductCard__link js-datalayer-catalog-list-name')
for index in range(len(element)):
    elem_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(element[index]), 'html.parser')
    title = elem_soup.find_all('a')[0].text
    title = ' '.join(title.split())
    print(title)
```

Comment: Полноценный ответ, к сожалению, написать не смогу, но могу посоветовать копнуть в сторону парсинга динамических скриптов. Есть ответы на первом же сайте в в гугле - https://qna.habr.com/q/365102. А вообще, если посмотреть в инспекторе, какие запросы делает сайт при прокручивании (`F12 -> Networks`), то идет подобный `GET` запрос `https://vkusvill.ru/goods/molochnye_produkty_yaytso/?PAGEN_1=2&_=1640303345845` (`id` написал рандомный), и при прокручивании к новым элементам `id` инкрементируется на 1, но не уверен, что это может полностью вам помочь. Наводку я вам дал - удачи.

Comment: Скорее всего причина такая же как и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s/1135231#1135231 а именно, програма должна ждать, когда javascript закончит выплонение, перед тем как читать и парсить страницу