# Проблема с работой в selenium

Tags: python, selenium, браузер, расширения

Есть проблема. Вот код -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep


def function_check_iz_sticker(link_or_skin_for_checking_t):


    # Установка базовых значений и расширения
    PATH_for_web_selenim = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe'
    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    PATH2_for_check_stickers = 'C:/Users/msi1/Desktop/help with skins/pre_alpha_10/information/other_what_some/extension_2_4_0_0.crx'
    opts.add_extension(PATH2_for_check_stickers)
    driver_selenium = webdriver.Chrome(PATH_for_web_selenim, options=opts)

    driver_selenium.get(link_or_skin_for_checking_t)
    search_selenium_1 = driver_selenium.find_element_by_css_selector("div.float-stickers-container")
    print(search_selenium_1)
    sleep(10)
```

Есть так же само расширение - CSGOFloat Market Checker.
Вот пример ссылки - [вот ссылка](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20P2000%20%7C%20Ivory%20%28Battle-Scarred%29?filter=%22Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%2C%20Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%2C%20Astralis%20Atlanta%202017%22).
И вот мне нужно получить данные div.float-stickers-container, но он не может найти их, более того, в коде страницы это есть, а в html коде - нет. Помогите решить проблему!

Comment: `в коде страницы это есть, а в html коде - нет.` - это что значит? Где и как смотрите "код страницы" и "html код"?

Comment: То есть, при открытии панели разработчика в браузере это есть, а при открытии в отдельной странице html кода - нет

Comment: Похоже, что после загрузки страницы, запускается javascript и ее меняет. Смотрите например тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s/1135231#1135231

Comment: Спасибо, помогло