# Почему WebDriver не находит элемент на странице через xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Почему этот код не работает?

```
 @Test
    public void login() {
        driver.get("https://market.yandex.ru/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/span/input")).click();
       
    }
```

Comment: Возможно проблема в том же что и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s/1135231

Comment: Первый способ у меня и так реализован в другом методе.А второй способ вызывает ошибку "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: /html/****/input (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)"

Comment: Про способы я не понял. Речь о том, что на странице много чего загружается javacript-ом. Это во-первых ведет к тому, что без ожидания программа еще не видит того, что добавляется динамически. А во-вторых, позиция элемента и его xpath меняется со временем. Как с этим бороться описано по ссылке выше

Comment: Там было два способа как решить проблему.Через implicitly_wait и этот способ у меня и так есть в коде,хоть и не показан.И второче через wait.untl(...).И вот тут возникает та самая ошибка,которую я привел выше