# Selenium не удается найти элемент (python)

Tags: python, selenium

Доброе время суток, начал изучать Selenium с определенной целью автоматизировать одну задачу. Но столкнулся с проблемой "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"
Нужно авторизоваться на сайте, но не получается найти элемент для ввода логина и пароля. Пробовал искать по ID, css, xpath. Пробовал с другими сайтами. с ними проблем не возникает никаких, а вот с нужным мне не получается. Так же пробовал решить проблему через Selenium IDE. в ней всё отрабатывает нормально, но если выданные значений подставляю в код пайтон, то всё равно получаю ошибку "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element".
Добрые люди, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так или в чём проблема? =(

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

username = "test"
password = 'test'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Distr/chromedriver')
browser.get('https://vmware.vmlab.ru/vsphere-client/?csp')

search_form = browser.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
search_form = browser.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
```

Проблема не в динамической загрузки сайта. Пробовал выставлять интервалы ожидания до 20 секунд. Как через: browser.implicitly_wait() так и просто: time.sleep(). Результат тот же.

[image: Код страницы сайта]

[image: Код полученный через Selenium IDE]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка NoSuchElementException Unable to locate element при нажатии на кнопку в selenium](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s) Причина проблемы та же, loginForm загружается динамически. Ее нет в изначальной версии страницы.

Comment: Пробовал выставлять интервалы ожидания до 20 секунд.

Как через:
`browser.implicitly_wait()`
так и просто:
`time.sleep()`

Если я неправильно Вас понял, просьба объяснить более подробно. Я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема заключалась во фрэйме - нужно было провалиться в него.

В моём случае:

```
    search_form = browser.switch_to_frame('websso')
```