# Почему не работает код? а именно хром открывается, а на кнопку не нажимается

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://demoqa.com/')

elementsbut = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]').click
```

Comment: Тут несколько проблем. Первая, что нужно ставить скобки для вызова функции, т.е. нужно чтоб было `.click()`. А во-вторых, загрузка страницы происходит асинхронно и тест должен ждать пока все произойдет, читайте подробности https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135155/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-nosuchelementexception-unable-to-locate-element-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-s/1135231#1135231

Comment: спасибо огромное)