# Почему selenium не может найти элемент?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Парсю сайт hh.ru с помощью selenium,а именно страницу https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=&st=searchVacancy&text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&fromSearch=true В некоторых вакансиях написано снизу 'показать контакты' или "позвонить", мне нужно спарсить эти контакты. Но не может найти элемент, css селектор правильно прописал. Но почему не может найти блок с контактами?

```
def parse_element(self, element):
        company_name = element.find_element_by_css_selector('div.vacancy-serp-item__meta-info > a.bloko-link.bloko-link_secondary')
        company_name = company_name.text
        contacts = element.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[11]/div[6]')
        contacts_info = contacts.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[11]/div[6]/span[1]')
        contacts_info.click()
        sleep(5)
        contact = element.find_element_by_css_selector('div.Bloko-Drop-Down.bloko-drop.bloko-drop_down.bloko-drop_theme-light.bloko-drop_layer-floating.bloko-drop_bottom.bloko-drop_fullscreen-on-xs.bloko-drop_clickable')
```

Код работает до "contacts_info.click()", он кликает, я это вижу, появляется блок с контактами,ставлю задержку, но после этого ищу, и вечно исключение **NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element** . Я уже все перепробовал, помогите пожалуйста.

```
<div class="Bloko-Drop-Down bloko-drop bloko-drop_down bloko-drop_theme-light bloko-drop_layer-floating bloko-drop_bottom bloko-drop_fullscreen-on-xs bloko-drop_clickable" data-qa="bloko-drop-down" style="top: 3210px; left: 418.719px;">
```

Это кусочек кода страницы, css селектор у меня правильно прописан.

Comment: Кажется это то что Вам нужно - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836240/201445

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy спасибо, но я ставил ожидания, это не помогло

Comment: Удалось найти решение? Опубликуйте пожалуйста, а то таже ошибка и с вызывом ожиданий не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно есть ограничение на количество классов у одного элемента. Но в любом случае, если уменьшить количество классов в строке селектора, то элемент находится.