# Python и Selenium, вопрос - почему делает только один запрос?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Код:

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        # self.options = Options()
        # self.options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def load_search(self):
        url = f'https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?area=&st=searchVacancy&text=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82&fromSearch=true'
        self.driver.get(url)
        container = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            'div.vacancy-serp-item.vacancy-serp-item_premium')
        for block in container:
            self.parse_block(block=block)

    def parse_block(self, block):
        block_list = []
        try:
            if not block.find_element_by_css_selector(
                    'span.bloko-link.bloko-link_dimmed'):
                pass
            else:
                block_list.append(block)
        except BaseException:
            pass
        for element in block_list:
            self.parse_url(element=element)

    def parse_url(self, element):
        url = element.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'a.bloko-link.HH-LinkModifier')
        href = url.get_attribute('href')
        self.parse_element(url=href)

    def parse_element(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        company_name = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            'div.bloko-gap.bloko-gap_bottom')
        print(company_name)
```

Интересуют последние три функции. В первой функции на каждой итерации цикла
`for element in block_list`
вызывается функция `parse_url` и в нее попадает первый веб элемент из списка `block_list`, затем эта функция ищет ссылку и передает ее в функцию `parse_element`, эта в свою очередь переходит по ссылке находит веб элемент и печатает его в консоль. И после этого в функцию `parse_url` попадает следующий веб элемент, и снова находится ссылка и передается в функцию `parse_element`, и найденный веб элемент должен снова выводится в консоль, и так далее. Но почему все это выполняется только один раз, ведь должно выполнятся столько, сколько веб элементов в `block_list`'e, т.е. на каждой итерации цикла?

Comment: Попробуйте дать вопросу более толковое название

Comment: У Selenium частенько бывает, что он не находит вовремя веб элементы (говорю по своему опыту). Я для начала посоветовал бы вывести список `block_list` в консоль, и убедиться, что элементов там несколько. Попробуйте так же добавить явное ожидание - может это Вам поможет.

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy хорошо, но по сути ведь должно работать? Да,селениум бывает не ищет  веб элементы, вот у меня есть вопрос, на него так и не дали ответа [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1146644/381776] . И да block_list не пустой,неоднократно проверял

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [API](https://github.com/hhru/api), жестких ограничений по поиску вакансий в документации не сказано

selenium не очень подходит для вашей задачи, тк изменения элементов в верстке сломает Ваше приложение